# Changing fonts in GNOME when tweak tool doesnt work

Tags: gnome, fonts, gnome-tweak-tool

I have a question.

I have recently installed ONLYOFFICE and the scaling on it doesnt work at all. I have it set to 1.25 in GNOME tweaks, but it seems to be stuck at 1.00 on ONLYOFFICE app.

My question is does anyone know how to set the font scaling to 1.25 manually for the app? I looked into apps settings and i found nothing, so i am wondering is there anything that could be done from terminal.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 BTW.

Thanks